# How to have separate mongodb log files

Tags: log-files, mongodb

We are using mongodb version 3 in a AWS environment with Linux AMIs.
I suspect this is not possible from reading the mongodb documentation.

I would like to log all slow queries to its own log file. When slow queries are logged they write the query data as well. I do not want query data going into my normal mongodb.log file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it will be possible to log slow queries into a separate log file. However, depending on the intent, there may be other options to achieve a similar result.

The best course of action will depend on the goal. Is the goal to:

- Access logs for slow query without having to look through a log file, or..
- Prevent logs of slow queries from appearing in the logs (e.g. queries can't be present for security reasons)

For the former, look into using the [Database Profiler](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/#profiling-levels), which can be configured to log slow queries to a system.profile collection.

For the latter, you may want to try looking into [customizing the verbosity settings of your logs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/log-messages/#verbosity-levels). It looks like it should be possible to entirely disable the logging of queries.

Comment: Great. I will look at the database profiler option.